# Copying Web Parts between pages in different web apps (SP2013)

Tags: web-part, powershell, migration

I am migrating sites between two different web apps, both in the same SharePoint 2013 farm. Both sites are pretty heavily customised (master pages, page layouts, content types, etc).

All attempts to migrate pages have failed (assigning different master pages, different page layouts, different content types - they're just too different).

My last resort (before I try  and get a band of people to manually copy and paste data from one page to the other, over and over again!), is to hope that  I can copy web parts (content editor, summary links, image, etc.) from the first page to another using PowerShell.

I'm hoping that I can do something like:

1. Identify the content in http://site1/pages/sample1.aspx
2. Create a new page, using the title and URL from the original page, as in
   http://site2/pages/sample1.aspx
3. Grab the web parts from the original page and drop them into the new page.

Is this possible? Can anyone help with the code (or point my in the right direction of a sample code)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came to the below. It exports the webparts locally,
**deletes them from the page**,
uploads them and inserts them into the Wiki Content on the page:

`$Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true;`

`$Page.CheckOut()`

`#Start moving web parts...`

`Write-host "========== Starting the web parts on" $Page.url " ======-ForegroundColor Green
    $errorMsg = "Test Error Message"
    $exportFolderPath = "D:\SharePoint\webpartsTemp"
    $wpm = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($Page.ListItem.Url, [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
    foreach($wp in $wpm.WebParts)
{
    $wp.ExportMode="All";
    $webpartfile = $wp.Title + ".xml"
    Write-host "=== Exporting " $webpartfile -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $exportPath = $exportFolderPath + "\"" + $webpartfile
    $xwTmp = new-object System.Xml.XmlTextWriter($exportPath,$null);
    $xwTmp.Formatting = 1;#Indent
    $wpm.ExportWebPart($wp, $xwTmp);
    $wpm.DeleteWebPart($wpm.WebParts[$wp.ID])
    $xwTmp.Flush();
    $xwTmp.Close();
    Write-host "Done exporting " $webpartfile
    Write-host "Loading xml..." 
    $wpxml = Get-Content -Path $exportPath
    # Initialize the XmlReaderSettings Object which is required for the XmlReader Object
    Write-host "Initialize the XmlReaderSettings Object which is required for the XmlReader Object"
    $xmlReaderSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings
    # Create the XmlReader Object by using the WebPart Definition file and the ReaderSettings Object
    Write-host "Create the XmlReader Object by using the WebPart Definition file and the ReaderSettings Object"
    $xmlReader = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create($exportPath,$xmlReaderSettings);
    #Add Web Part to catalogs folder and Get the WebPart Definition Object based on the webpart definition xml file

    Write-host "Add Web Part to catalogs folder and Get the WebPart Definition Object based on the webpart definition xml file    " -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $oWebPartDefinition = $wpm.ImportWebPart($xmlReader,[ref]$errorMsg);
    ## Create the web part.
    # Create a guid and storage key
    Write-host "Create a guid and storage key"
    $documentsWebPartGuid = [System.Guid]::NewGuid()
    $documentsWebPartId = "g_" + $documentsWebPartGuid.ToString().Replace("-","_") 
    # Create a new web part
    Write-host "Create a new web part"
    $documentsWebPart = $oWebPartDefinition
    # Give the web part an Id
    Write-host "Give the web part an Id"
    $documentsWebPart.ID = $documentsWebPartId 
    # Tell it to use the default view
    Write-host "Tell it to use the default view"
    $documentsWebPart.Title = $wp.Title
    ## Create the Wiki Content
    Write-host "Create the Wiki Content"
    $Page.ListItem['Page Content'] = $Page.ListItem['Page Content'] + @"
    <p>​</p>
    <div class='ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox' contenteditable='false' defaultpastemoderesolver='PastePlain'>
    <div class='ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read $($documentsWebPartGuid.ToString('D'))' id='div_$($documentsWebPartGuid.ToString('D'))'>
    </div>
    <div id='vid_$($documentsWebPartGuid.ToString('D'))' style='display: none;'>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p>&#160;</p>
    "@
    $Page.ListItem.Update()
    # Add the web parts to the page
    Write-host "Add the web parts to the page"
    $wpm.AddWebPart($documentsWebPart,'wpz',0)
    $Page.ListItem.Update();
    # Remove expired xml
    Write-host "Remove expired xml"
    Remove-Item $exportPath
    }
           #Done with web parts...`

May have to add the webparts to an array, and then work through that array (to prevent the script failing as soon as the first web part is removed), but this works.**strong text**

Comment: Carefull. This script deletes data. Be sure you understand it correctly before executing.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a 3rd party solution. This will ensure you will get all items and are not missing some dependencies you overlooked. This will likely be more hassle free than moving the stuff yourself.

Not suggesting any company out there, but the names should be known.